# Cannot implicitly convert type 'F_M.Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type' to 'F_M.Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type[]'

Tags: c#, workday-api

I am trying to use the "Put_Ledger" function inside the Financial_management API in Workday, but I keep on getting an error when I try to add the `object[]` to the object (as it states in the API to do).

Workday has been no help in solving this issue. Here is a sample of the code. The objects are creates, and then added to parent objects:

```
Ledger_Only_DataType ldOnly = new Ledger_Only_DataType
{
    Actuals_Ledger_ID = "1234567",
    Can_View_Budget_Date = true
};

//Commitment_Ledger_data
Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type cl = new Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type
{
    Commitment_Ledger_Reference = ledgerObject,
    Enable_Commitment_Ledger = true,
    Spend_Transaction_Data = st,
    Payroll_Transaction_Data = pt
};

// This is where the error occurs:
ldOnly.Commitment_Ledger_Data = cl;
```

Error message:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'CallWorkdayAPI.Financial_Management.Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type' to 'CallWorkdayAPI.Financial_Management.Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type[]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with Workday, but I am assuming

```
ldOnly.Commitment_Ledger_Data
```

Is an *array* of: `Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type`

So you need to set it equal to an array of that type, whereas currently you are setting it equal to a single object of that type.

```
Ledger_Only_DataType ldOnly = new Ledger_Only_DataType
       {
           Actuals_Ledger_ID = "1234567",
           Can_View_Budget_Date = true
       };

       //Commitment_Ledger_data
       Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type cl = new 
         Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type
       {
           Commitment_Ledger_Reference = ledgerObject,
           Enable_Commitment_Ledger = true,
           Spend_Transaction_Data = st,
           Payroll_Transaction_Data = pt
       };

       Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type[] cls = new Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type[1];

       cls[0] = cl;

       ldOnly.Commitment_Ledger_Data = cls;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lists and convert them to an array. It's easier:

```
    List<Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type> cls = new List<Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type>();

    Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type cl1 = new 
         Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type
       {
           Commitment_Ledger_Reference = ledgerObject,
           Enable_Commitment_Ledger = true,
           Spend_Transaction_Data = st,
           Payroll_Transaction_Data = pt
       };

    cls.Add(cl1);

   ldOnly.Commitment_Ledger_Data = cls.ToArray();
```

You can simplify and do it inside the initializer as well

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what the problem is - you're trying to assign a single instance of a `Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type` type to an object that represents an array of that type (`Commitment_Ledger_Data`).

You should be able to do the assignment using an array (with the single item you created as it's only member) instead:

```
ldlOnly.Commitment_Ledger_Data = new[] {cl};
```

Or you could shorten the whole thing to use initializer syntax:

```
var ldOnly = new Ledger_Only_DataType
{
    Actuals_Ledger_ID = "1234567",
    Can_View_Budget_Date = true,
    Commitment_Ledger_Data = new[]
    {
        new Commitment_Ledger_Data__Public_Type
        {
            Commitment_Ledger_Reference = ledgerObject,
            Enable_Commitment_Ledger = true,
            Spend_Transaction_Data = st,
            Payroll_Transaction_Data = pt
        }
    }
};
```